# How to select columns by position in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with dozens of columns. I want to select a number of columns throughout the dataframe. Is there a better way than writing out all the column names? For example, I tried the following and I didn't work:

```
cols = df_all.columns[10:21]
cols2 = df_all.columns[-1]

df_all[cols : cols2].head()
```

I suppose I could create two dataframes first then join them, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine column indexes you can also do this:

```
df_all[df_all.columns[10:21] | df_all.columns[-1:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the `:` and add a `|` and you're there, but I'm adding a little code to make the example clearer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
columns=list(string.ascii_uppercase)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,26), columns=columns)
cols = df.columns[10:21]
cols2 = df.columns[-1:]
df[cols | cols2]
```

In your original code, cols2 was just the last element in the index, not an index of all columns from the last one on (which would just be one element). Your last line was trying to slice between two indexes (I think) but what I think you want is to combine the two (using the `|`)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort the columns by the name of the columns use pandas and `.loc()` if you prefer by column numner use `.iloc()`

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.DataFrame([[1, 2,5,2], [5,4, 5,4], [7,7, 8,1], [7,6,9,2]], 
                    columns=['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4'])

    df
       col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
    0      1      2      5      2
    1      5      4      5      4
    2      7      7      8      1
    3      7      6      9      2
```

apply `loc()`

```
    df_names=df.loc[:,'col_2':'col_4']

    df_names
       col_2  col_3  col_4
    0      2      5      2
    1      4      5      4
    2      7      8      1
    3      6      9      2
```

apply `.iloc` on column 2 to 4:

```
    df_2_4=df.iloc[:,1:4]


    df_2_4
       col_2  col_3  col_4
    0      2      5      2
    1      4      5      4
    2      7      8      1
    3      6      9      2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; very insightful how ```loc``` and ```iloc``` work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df_all.ix(location)` to access a column by location or using `df_all.icol(int)` by an integer value. You can also do this:

```
df_all[df_all.columns[2]]
```